# Views user content value using php argument

Tags: drupal, view

Just trying to use php argument in drupal views.

I need PHP that will check on a users cck content profile field value.

True if it is 'on' 
false if it not 'on'

Sorry designer not coder.

Comment: Sorry I don't completely understand what you're trying to do. Please describe what kind of data the user profile contains, what your view displays and which effect the argument value should have on the view.

Comment: Basically I have a group of users that can make notes on documents that I have on our website. These notes are displayed by default to that user under the document when they visit that page. I want them to also be able to stipulate which users can see each note if at all. Rather than choosing by the user name or ID, I have sub groups of users. Rather than using OG or roles (These are in use for other things) I have created catagories that are just on/off check boxes on a user cck content profile node (I'm thinking of moving these to main profile page) I just need a truth value = on for views

Comment: A PHP code that will return a true value if the check box for a certain duty (lets say eg: 'stock order staff') on the current logged in user's duties page (duties is what the profile content type is called) is ticked (on).
Sorry if I've made this more confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did swap the content from a filed value of cck content profile type to a value within the main part of the users profile.
Now I can use this php argument to validate whether a user can see a note or not using a view.

```
global $user;

profile_load_profile($user);

if ($user->profile_does_cashregister == 1)
return TRUE;
else 
return FALSE;
```

I would still like to know how to use a simular validator to filter content based on a value from a cck content profile field.